# Web.config: Rewrite Rule is not working

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have following rewrite rule in ASP.NET MVC 4 application :

```
<rule name="Old Product Detail Page" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="pd\.asp\?productid=([0-9]+)$"/>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/Product/Old/{R:1}"/>
 </rule>
```

when I try to access `/pd.asp?productid=12345` in browser, it says `"Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /pd.asp"`

But I did test above pattern in http://regex101.com and it says one match found. see http://regex101.com/r/hU9cR9/2

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried starting your match url with `/`?

Comment: Yes, tried with / but no luck.